# Configure aws API gateway for public (anonymous user)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I made AWS API gateway  as public and i am trying to test it in localhost server
But i got this error

```
{
  Message: 'User: anonymous is not authorized to perform: execute-api:Invoke on resource: arn:aws:execute-api:ap-northeast-2:********8648:vftnbscanh/test/POST/sms/send/'        
}
```

with this headers

```
error.response.headers
{
  date: 'Sun, 04 Apr 2021 09:07:17 GMT',
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  'content-length': '170',
  connection: 'close',
  'x-amzn-requestid': '9e30546f-d9a2-4091-bd08-1635b6c8eca0',
  'x-amzn-errortype': 'AccessDeniedException',
  'x-amz-apigw-id': 'dQE25FsiIE0FsOA='
}
```

HUMMM i thought i configured well check my configure.

[image]

Comment: Did you setup IAM authorization or api resource policy so that it blocks access? By default it is public.

Comment: @Marcin  Thanks! i just copy my another api gateway and the resource policy was wrong! :)

Comment: Glad it worked out. If you don't mind I will provide an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was caused by **incorrect API resource-based policy**. By default, new API is public and does not have any policy. But since the API was created by copying an existing one, the per-existing policy was prohibiting public access.

Remove the policy and **re-deploying** the API stage can fix the issue.